# How to replace attachment in gmail message using gmail api & google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, email-attachments

I have requirement to replace or remove an attachment from mail body using gmail api in google app script.

Does anyone have any direct or indirect solutions please let me know.

i have gone threw this documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail but did not found any working solution.

Comment: You cant change a message that has been sent.

Comment: yes, true we can not modify original message.

Answer (score 0):

As per googles policy, original message can not be modified, so i have picked up attachment from mail and replied in same thread with my modified attachment.